# View changes made to a file in Windows

Tags: windows-10, notepad

Yesterday, I made a change to an existing **text file** using **Notepad** in my **PC** (Windows 10). Today, I need to get the old version back. I tried **restoring previous versions**. But none is there.

- Is it possible to view the changes made to the file?
- Or is it possible to retrieve the old file?

Comment: Most likely, you'll be unable to recover your unchanged document easily if Windows did not save a copy and you don't have a regular backup schedule or program running in the background. I've had this happen one too many times and have had to start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

That's possible if you configure the File History. As you can see, previous version come from File History or from restore points.
[image]

If you haven't configure File History or System restore point, you cannot retrieve it.

Comment: Sadly, I didn't configure it.

Comment: If so, I am afraid that you cannot get the previous version if you have no another backup.